# Android Linear Layout - How to Keep Element At Bottom Of View?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a `TextView` which I want to pin at the bottom of a landscape activity that is using `LinearLayout` with vertically arranged elements.

I have set `android:gravity="bottom"` on the text view, but it still likes to be just below the last element of the `LinearLayout` exactly what I do not want it to do.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just remove the `android:gravity="bottom"` from `TextView` and add it to the `LinearLayout`. Your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

**Update: I still get upvotes on this question, which is still the accepted answer and which I think I answered poorly. In the spirit of making sure the best info is out there, I have decided to update this answer.**

**In modern Android I would use `ConstraintLayout` to do this. It is more performant and straightforward.**

```
<ConstraintLayout>
   <View
      android:id="@+id/view1"
      ...other attributes elided... />
   <View
      android:id="@id/view2"        
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view1" />
      ...other attributes elided... />

   ...etc for other views that should be aligned top to bottom...

   <TextView
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
```

**If you don't want to use a ConstraintLayout, using a LinearLayout with an expanding view is a straightforward and great way to handle taking up the extra space (see the answer by @Matthew Wills). If you don't want to expand the background of any of the Views above the bottom view, you can add an invisible View to take up the space.**

**The answer I originally gave works but is inefficient. Inefficiency may not be a big deal for a single top level layout, but it would be a terrible implementation in a `ListView` or `RecyclerView`, and there just isn't any reason to do it since there are better ways to do it that are roughly the same level of effort and complexity if not simpler.**

Take the TextView out of the LinearLayout, then put the LinearLayout and the TextView inside a RelativeLayout. Add the attribute `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to the TextView. With all the namespace and other attributes except for the above attribute elided:

```
<RelativeLayout>
  <LinearLayout>
    <!-- All your other elements in here -->
  </LinearLayout>
  <TextView
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This did resolve the issue.  I am using a specific height for elements within the linear layout

Comment: If you're switching to RelativeLayout, might it be better to do away with the LinearLayout altogether, thus avoiding unnecessarily nested layouts?

Comment: For something like a layout inflated 100's or 1000's of times for a ListView, definitely. For a single layout for an Activity, it's not much of a hit. You're trading off programmer convenience for a tiny performance hit.

Comment: This doesn't work for Buttons inside a LinearLayout.

Comment: The question was about LinearLayout. In some cases, it's much preferable to use it instead of ConstraintLayout or RelateveLayout. I think this answer should contain a solution for Linear layout first and other solutions after that as optional.

Answer (score 134):

You will have to expand one of your upper views to fill the remaining space by setting `android:layout_weight="1"` on it. This will push your last view down to the bottom.

Here is a brief sketch of what I mean:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">
    <View/>
    <View android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <View/>
    <View android:id="@+id/bottom"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

where each of the child view heights is `"wrap_content"` and everything else is `"fill_parent"`.

Comment: How about if the elements have specific height like 40dp?

Comment: You must add width and height:
 <View android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

Comment: This is more efficient than the accepted answer as it has only one ViewGroup.

Comment: This is amazing.  I always forget this trick and end up spending forever messing with my layouts.  This is just amazing.  Solves world hunger.

Comment: Superior of all answers so far!

Comment: This should be correct answer! Not just because only one LinearLayout is used, but when you are inflating DialogFragment with needed layout design(some views should be on the bottom), this can comes handy because for some reason I received _android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: ..._ when using RelativeLayout and everything works great when using LinearLayout.

Comment: Simple and clean solution. Must be selected as the correct answer. Also proves that weights are no pushovers.

Comment: @Androider it suppose to be the accepted answer, upper one is just work around. It also working fine even for list view items.

Answer (score 66):

I think it will be perfect solution:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Other views -->
    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <!-- Target view below -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It is a good solution, but only works on Level 14 API and above.

Comment: @renatojf You can also try to use empty view or layout instead of space

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what I needed and didn't require me to do any layout nesting. I think you have the superior answer.

Comment: You are genius man !! i am wasting 2 days for this but miss something there thanks  (Not use relative and component is view pager i my layout so its creating problem)  -- I want to give more than one point but cant

Answer (score 12):

Step 1 : Create two view inside a linear layout

Step 2 : First view must set to android:layout_weight="1"

Step 3 : Second view will automatically putted downwards

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/botton_header"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_health_advice"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 12):

You should put the parameter **gravity to bottom** not in the textview but **in the Linear Layout**. Like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom|end">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Something"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
```

for your textview

Answer (score 1):

DO LIKE THIS

```
 <LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/LinearLayouts02"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="bottom|end">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/texts1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:text="@string/forgotpass"
    android:padding="7dp"
    android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="50dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:topRightRadius="10dp"
   />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use `android:gravity="bottom"` in LinearLayout

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewProfileName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```