# How to get a TextView at the bottom of the screen under a listview?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout, textview

I'm making a settings screen in my android app. This list of course has a pre defined set of options (notifications/colors/log out/etc.). So I decided to create the list statically in xml. Because the list should equally well display if it has more content than the screen I nested my `LinearLayout`within a `ScrollView` (couldn't use a `ListView` because I want to statically define the items in it).

This works fine with the following code now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black" >

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:paddingTop="30dp"
            android:text="@string/account_notifications" 
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"/>
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:text="@string/colors" 
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" />

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:text="@string/log_out" 
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

As you can see I set the background of the `LinearLayout` to black and the items to white, with a `marginBottom` of `1dp`, so that there is a separator between the list items. I now want the logout `TextView` always at the bottom of the screen. In case there are more items than the screen can hold, the Logout should simply be situated at the end of the list.

To get the logout to the bottom of the screen I found some solutions in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425341/android-linear-layout-how-to-keep-element-at-bottom-of-view). I first use the first suggestion like so:

```
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout 
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/black" >

            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_height"
                android:text="@string/account_notifications" 
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"/>

            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_height"
                android:text="@string/colors" 
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_height"
                android:text="@string/log_out" 
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" 
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

This surprisingly makes the logout `TextView` totally disappear. So I tried the second suggestion like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black" >

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_height"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/account_notifications" 
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"/>

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_height"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/colors" 
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" />
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_height"
            android:text="@string/log_out" 
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

But this unfortunately doesn't do anything either. No clue why not.

So my question, does anybody know how I can get my logout to the bottom of the screen, or in case the list is to long for the screen, to the bottom of the list.

All tips are welcome!

Comment: You want to have the logout button inside the listview? or you want to have the listview and then the logout button after the listview?

Comment: How about using "layout_above" attribute in LinearLayout of the second code. ex. android:layout_above="@+id/log_out_textview"

Answer (score 0):

```
Button btnLogout = new Button(this);
    btnLogout.setText("logout");

    // Adding logout button to lisview at bottom
    lv.addFooterView(btnLogout);
```

Here lv is the listview object. You can do the same with textview or any other view.

Comment: The thing is that because I want to manually populate my list, I cannot use a listView. For this reason I am using a LinearLayout, and using there's no method addFooterView for the type LinearLayout. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can add footer view of listview, it will display bottom of listview.

```
    private View footerView;

    footerView = ((LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(
                    R.layout.footer_layout, null, false);

    TextView textview = (TextView) footerView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textview);

listview.addFooterView(footerView);
```

Take one layout name footer_layout. in this one layout take one Textview. after that you can use above code. 
May be helpful to you.

Comment: Hi bro, can you join this chat room. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/141336/android-learning?tab=general I have to discuss few things over there.

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="color/black"
              android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:paddingTop="30dp"
                    android:text="@string/account_notifications"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"/>
            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:text="@string/colors"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:text="@string/log_out"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to fix the Logout `TextView` at the bottom of your screen , you can try this :

```
    <ScrollView
                  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:background="color/black"
                  android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >

          <RelativeLayout
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:paddingTop="30dp"
                        android:text="@string/account_notifications"
                        android:background="@color/white"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"/>
                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:text="@string/colors"
                        android:background="@color/white"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtLogout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:text="@string/log_out"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
       </RelativeLayout>
   </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. The thing is that there if there are more than the screen can fit, it starts overlapping, which is not good. If there are more than the screen can fit, the item should simply be appended to the end of the list.

Comment: do you want to have the logout textView to be fixed at the bottom of your screen . or at the bottom of your scrollView ?

Comment: When the list does not fill the whole screen (i.e.: is not long enough) I want the logout to be fixed at the bottom of my screen. When the list is too long for the screen however (in case of a small screen for example) I want the logout to be appended to the end of the list. Is this even possible?

Comment: you can replace the LinearLayout with a RelativeLayout , and then put the TextView Logout inside the RelativeLayout , and align it at the bottom of your screen. see my edits