# How can I position control at end of activity?

Tags: android, xml

[image]

I want to add a control at end of activity, There is my activity xml file, I need 
note_date be at end of activity.

Thank you all.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/note_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/note_title_hint" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/note_body"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="401dp"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:hint="@string/note_body_hint"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/note_date"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/note_date_hint"
    android:inputType="datetime" />
```

Comment: try to set `android:gravity:="bottom"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Linear Layout - How to Keep Element At Bottom Of View?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425341/android-linear-layout-how-to-keep-element-at-bottom-of-view)

Comment: You can use `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` for LinearLayout and `android:alignParentBottom="true"` for RelativeLayout. Please google well before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/note_date"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/note_date"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Comment: Thank you, but what is <LinearLayout... in middle of xml?

Comment: <LinearLayout... represents the empty space area.

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    tools:context=".Activity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:ems="10"
       >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```